How to version multiple github actions with in a same repo?
I am planning to crate multiple github action which are slightly related (so creating them in a same repo). One of the action has more up coming features to come. So, I want both the actions to have different versions.
Example :
action1@v5
action2@v1
Both these actions are to present in same repo but different folders. Is this possible ? How to achieve this ?
Couldn't find a solution for this in the documentation
